# How to fill the dataset with the Entity Framework database.sqlquery?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I using EntityFramewrok and I want to bind a class with stored procedure.

My procedure select query :

```
Select RecordId,Name_TrTr Name from Institute where Name_TrTr  like ('%'+@Search+'%')
 Order by Name
 OFFSET @Start ROWS
 FETCH NEXT @Length ROWS ONLY

Select @TotalCount as TotalCount, @FilteredCount FilteredCount
```

My Classses :

```
public class InstituteTestModel
{
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProcedureDetail
{
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public int FilteredCount { get; set; }
}

public class ProcedureClass
{
    public InstituteTestModel Model { get; set; }
    public ProcedureDetail Detail { get; set; }
}
```

C# execute:

```
var q = Connection.Database<ProcedureClass>(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the result in a datatable and convert your datatable to list

```
public static class Helper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a DataTable to a list with generic objects
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Generic object</typeparam>
    /// <param name="table">DataTable</param>
    /// <returns>List with generic objects</returns>
    public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();

            foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
            {
                T obj = new T();

                foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                list.Add(obj);
            }

            return list;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```